# Sitecore 9 update 2 installation failure with certificate error

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, sitecore-install-assistant

[image]

I accidentally broke my Sitecore instance, thus removed everything following this :
https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/02/20/failed-sitecore-installation-clean-up-checklist/

and trying to reinstall a new instance but it fails again and again with the attached error.

Please let me know what am I missing here. attaching the log file as well.

Log File:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20211216011445
Username: HCLTECH\samridhi.sachdeva
RunAs User: HCLTECH\samridhi.sachdeva
Configuration Name: 
Machine: LP-5CD8471464 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0)
Host Application: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe
Process ID: 20544
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1801
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.1801
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.1801
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\cb\xconnect-createcert.211216 (2).log
                                                                         ************************************
                                                                              Sitecore Install Framework
                                                                                   Version - 1.2.1
                                                                         ************************************


WorkingDirectory  : C:\cb
LogPath           : C:\cb\xconnect-createcert.211216 (2).log
WhatIf            : False
Verbose           : SilentlyContinue
Configuration     : C:\cb\build\assets\xconnect-createcert.json
Debug             : SilentlyContinue
WarningAction     : Continue
ErrorAction       : Stop
InformationAction : Continue




[---------------------------------------------------------------------------- CreatePaths : EnsurePath -----------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[CreatePaths]:[Create] c:\certificates

[------------------------------------------------------------------------- CreateRootCert : NewRootCertificate ---------------------------------------------------------------------]

FileInfo                         Certificate
--------                         -----------
C:\certificates\SitecoreRoot.crt [Subject]...



[------------------------------------------------------------------ ImportRootCertificate : ImportCertificate ----------------------------------------------------------------------]


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\Root

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
16F74B6D4B69324F09344EA084FECEDCF298BC86  CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by https://www.sitecore.net



[----------------------------------------------------------------------- CreateSignedCert : NewSignedCertificate -------------------------------------------------------------------]
**********************
Command start time: 20211216011450
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(New-SelfSignedCertificate): "CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)"
>> TerminatingError(New-SelfSignedCertificate): "CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)"
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Object already exists. 0x8009000f 
(-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)
At C:\cb\install-xp0.ps1:195 char:8
+        Install-SitecoreConfiguration $XConnectCertificateConfiguratio ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)
At C:\cb\install-xp0.ps1:195 char:8
+        Install-SitecoreConfiguration $XConnectCertificateConfiguratio ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:05
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20211216011450
**********************


enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach helped me resolve the issue:

Step 1: Delete all certificates from MMC under Current user and Local machine

Step 2: Create root Certificates

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -FriendlyName "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Step 3: Create the xConnect Certificate and replace the "ABC.xconnect" in the below script with your Instance name which will use in the installation script prefix parameter.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "ABC.xconnect" -FriendlyName "ABC.xconnect" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Step 4: Create the website Certificate and replace the "ABC.sc " in the below script with your Instance name which provide in the installation script prefix parameter.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "ABC.sc" -FriendlyName "ABC.sc" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Step 5: Open In the Local computer MMC using this command `"certlm.msc"`
Copy all the above 3 certificates from personal to trusted root certificates Authorities.

Step 6 : Now Run your Installation PowerShell script, with names of certificates you have created manually.

Answer (score 0):

Exception you're getting is `Object already exists`.

Most probably you're trying to create certificates with same names as you already have.

Try deleting certificates which were used by your previous instance as described in here:

https://blog.coates.dk/2018/11/08/sitecore-sif-newsignedcertificate-the-time-period-is-invalid/

Comment: I don't have any certificates as i have deleted all as per best of my knowledge.